# Accounts that hit >=41 days past due 171 Days Prior & Remained >=41

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, datediff

for 171 consecutive days on the 171st date and when the date of the 171st date occurs as of the last processing/business date, ie, PROCDATE. I've written the below query, essentially utilizing two CTEs but it doesn't work. Specifically, it's producing accounts that were at least 41 days past due consistently for 171 days but NOT as of the last processing date, ie, PROCDATE.  I also can't report loans that may have dropped below 41 days, and I can't report loans that simply were at least 41 days past due for 171 days unless they hit the 171 on PROCDATE, so to further demonstrate exactly I need to report, most relate to the following scenarios:
1.  An account drops above and below 41 days before eventually staying >= 41 days for 171 days. I only want to report such loans from the time they went >= 41 days past due for 171 consecutive business days as of PROCDATE.
2.  An account goes >= 41 days past due and never going greater than 41 days for 171 straight days as of PROCDATE.
3.  An account goes >= 41 days past due and then never gets below 41 and hovers between 41 and 100+ days past due as of PROCDATE.
I'm sure there are other scenarios, but I need to capture accounts that meet the criteria as of the last processing day, ie, PROCDATE.  I can't report loans that met the criteria two or more days ago, a week ago, etc. That's key.

Unfortunately, my report doesn't capture the loans that hit the criteria on PROCDATE. It's capturing all loans that have been >=41 days in the past regardless of PROCDATE and regardless of when they went >= 41 days. One loan met the criteria but as of 20181101, not as of the PROCDATE which for today is yesterday 20181206.  As importantly, it also doesn't correctly capture the loans from the last time they went >= 41 days past due.  One loan the below code reports had been running over 100 days past due and as of PROCDATE it was 122 days past due since (and before) 20160611 but met the 171 days on 20181129. Therein I think likes the solution – it's incorrect to SET @BEGDATE back 171 days from PROCDATE without considering then they first went >= 41 days. My first and separate report simply looks at all loans that hit >= 41 days when on the prior day they were < 41 days past due (every time). The solution for was, in short: 
((ISNULL(li.PDDAYSREG,0) >= 42) and ISNULL(ld.PDDAYSREG,0) <  42)

The tables used for this report (the field names used are pretty self-explanatory):
dbo.dim_dates = trending table of all FULLDATEs, ie, all processing dates back to 20071231
dbo.tbl_Daily_Processing_Dates = daily table of various processing dates, ie, PROCDATE = last processing/business date 
dbo.tbl_loan_daily_info = daily table of many fields for all accounts
dw.Loan_Daily_Info = trending/history table containing most of the same fields in the dbo.tbl_loan_daily_info

### Any help would be sincerely appreciated, and I don't have DB rights :-(

```
DECLARE @BEGDATE datetime, @PROCDATE datetime;

SET @PROCDATE = (SELECT PROCDATE FROM 
dbo.tbl_Daily_Processing_Dates);
SET @BEGDATE  = (SELECT NextProcessingDate FROM dbo.dim_Dates WHERE 
FullDate = DATEADD(dd, -171, @PROCDATE));

WITH PD_CTE (PROCDATE, ACCTNO, NXTPAYDATE, LSTPMTDATE, PDDAYS, 
PDITOT)
AS (
SELECT PROCDATE, ACCTNO, NXTPAYDATE, LSTPMTDATE, PDDAYSREG
FROM dbo.tbl_Loan_Daily_Info
WHERE PDDAYS BETWEEN 41 AND 211 --221=41+170
),

PDMINMAX_CTE (ACCTNO, MIN_PDDAYS, MAX_PDDAYS, DAY_COUNT, MIN_DATE, 
MAX_DATE)
AS (
SELECT 
A.ACCTNO, MIN(B.PDDAYS) as MIN_PDDAYS, MAX(B.PDDAYS) as MAX_PDDAYS, 
COUNT(*) AS DAY_COUNT, MIN(B.FILEDATE) as MIN_DATE, 
MAX(B.FILEDATE) as MAX_DATE
FROM PD_CTE as A
INNER JOIN dw.Loan_Daily_Info as B
   ON A.ACCTNO = B.ACCTNO AND B.ACTYPE = 'L'
WHERE B.FILEDATE BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND @PROCDATE
GROUP BY A.ACCTNO
)

SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dd, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE) as DATE_DIFF, @PROCDATE, 
@BEGDATE
FROM PDMINMAX_CTE
WHERE MIN_PDDAYS >= 41 AND MAX_PDDAYS >= 41 
ORDER BY ACCTNO;
```

`

Comment: Hey dfundako, I don't use the Board a lot - but would appreciate an interpretation of your message.  Simply trying to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of information here but you should use a CASE statement for this. You are using the where clause to separate your dates but you can do a CASE statement for that and then call that field whatever you want.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time for a response Gutzy.

Comment: Not a problem @Craig, if you have any issues let me know!

Comment: Thanks again Gutzy. Will likely reach back out after I work on my Case statements - have done plenty, but most have been fairly straight-forward.

Comment: Hi @Craig, just checking if this solved your problem?

Comment: had to set this aside due to the Holidays and some deployments, but am just getting back to this - and am still stuck in the mud,  Working on it now - do you have any tidbits?  Sincere thanks!